# Unable to update a graph made with Chart.JS. chart.update(); seems not to work

Tags: javascript, chart.js

*Hello, I am a 57 year old Frenchman beginner in web programming in particular javascript...
My English dates from 40 years ago (2 years at school, hope that Google translation will not make too many mistakes...)*

I have a graph in javascript (made by Chart.JS) **I'm trying to make title updates, to remove data to put others as in the following examples**:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/samples/line/line.html

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

And of course it doesn't work for me...

Here are my javascript functions (in the html file for now)

`

```
    
function test(){

Y=[
    '01-01-2023 10:15',                                         
    '01-01-2023 10:30',                                         
    '01-01-2023 10:45',
    ],
    X=[ 141.00, 181.00, 241.00,];
    
    console.table(Y);
    console.table(X);
    console.table(data);
}   // de test  
    
    function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
    console.log ('we removed the data');
}
    
    
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();

    console.log ('we had to update');
}
function updateConfigByMutating(chart) {
    chart.options.plugins.title.text = 'new title';
    chart.update();
    console.log ('we had to update the title');
}

</script>
```

`I trigger them from a menu:`

```
    <nav class="menu align-center">
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Chart menu</h2>
    </header>

    <ul id="menu-poids">
        <li>   
            <span class="opener">Weight parameters</span>
            <ul>
                <li onclick="test()"> création 2 tableaux fixe </li>
                <li onclick="updateConfigByMutating(chart)"> title </li>
                <li onclick="removeData(chart)"> remove </li>
                <li onclick="addData(chart,Y,X)"> add data </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

`
Already 1st point for me in the functions the chart parameter ex updateConfigByMutating(chart) could be any name given to my chart... well I had called this chart myChart and I was getting errors...

To try to make simple I renamed it chart I can get to the console tracer; log ('a text to see where I am'); but nothing happens no title update, remove data, or add (well the add I'm not sure I wrote the thing right yet)

Here is the source code I use to create my graph:
`

```
    <!--*********** weight graph***********************-->

<br>
<div class="mes_h2"><strong><span style="color:red">weight</span></strong></div>
    

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>        <!-- creation of the canvas tag named chart-->

<script>

labels = [
<?php                       
    for($i = 0, $i = count($tab_stamp)-1 ; $i >= 0; $i--){
?> 
    '<?= $tab_stamp[$i]['date']?>',
                                            
<?php     
    }
?>
    ];


data = {
                                                labels: labels,
                                                datasets: [{
                                                    label:'<?= $NumRuche?>',
                                                    backgroundColor: "green",
                                                    borderColor: "blue",

 //sets an empty array by default
                                                  data:[],
    }]
    };


data = {
                                                labels: labels,
                                                datasets: [{
                                                    label: 'Weight',    
                                                    backgroundColor: "yellow",
                                                    borderColor: "black",
                                                    data: [<?php for($i = 0, $i = count($tab_mas)-1 ; $i >= 0; $i--){?> <?= $tab_mas[$i]['masse']?>,<?php } ?>],
    }]
    };


const config = {
                                                type: 'line',   
                                                data:data,
                                                options: {
                                                    aspectRatio: 2, 
                                                                    
                                                        plugins: {
                                                            title: {                    // graphic title
                                                            display: true,
                                                            text: 'Weight'
                                                            },  //end of title
                                                        subtitle:   {           // subtitle graphics
                                                            display: true,
                                                            text:  'Ruche N°<?=$NumRuche?>'
                                                        },  // fin du sous titre
                                                        },          // end of plugins

                                                responsive: true,
                                                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                                                scales: {       
                                                    x: {                                                                        display: true,  
                                                            title: {
                                                                display: true,
                                                                text: 'Date hour',      
                                                                color: '#911',      
                                                                font: {     
                                                                    family: 'Comic Sans MS',
                                                                    size: 20,   
                                                                    weight: 'bold',     
                                                                    lineHeight: 1.2,
                                                                },
                                                                padding: {top: 10, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}        
                                                            }   
                                                    },  
                                                    
                                                    y: {
                                                        display: true,
                                                            title: {
                                                                display: true,
                                                                text: 'Kg',             
                                                                color: '#191',          
                                                                font: {                 
                                                                    family: 'Times',
                                                                    size: 20,
                                                                    style: 'normal',
                                                                    lineHeight: 1.2
                                                                       }, 
                                                                padding: {top: 30, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}    
                                                            }   

                                                        }

} 
}   
                                                                        };
</script>


<script>
                                                                                                context = document.getElementById('chart').getContext("2d");
                                                                        chart = new Chart(context, config);                                           
</script>
```

`
I think I followed the example of:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/samples/line/line.html
yet it does not work no request for change even that of the title no error message, nothing in the console just my display to say that I passed in the function...
If anyone knows how to make this work, I would greatly appreciate it!

PS: I use the chart.js library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

I tried this too but it's the same thing!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-ElRFoEQdI5Ht6kZvyzXhYG9NqjtkmlkfYk0wr6wHxU9JEHakS7UJZNeml5ALk+8IKlU6jDgMabC3vkumRokgreran="origincyous"onymRokgreran=referpolian="crosspoliny" ="no-referrer"></script>
```

Thanks

```
**So I found all my charts were declared with the same name: "chart**" and suddenly my modification requests related to the last one that I was not viewing...
/* Create the chart */
chart = new Chart(context3, config3); for all the graphs I had only realized that it named the graph.

The change title function works very well.
The one to remove data works but it only removes one data at a time is it possible to completely empty the table of the graph?

**I can't find the removedataset function**
I found how to remove all data **but not how to remove all labels..**..

        function removeDataSet(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();     //remove a single label
    chart.data.datasets.pop();  // remove all data
    
    chart.update();

}   

**It's a bit the same for adding data, I'm desperately looking for the adddataset function (to add a complete table and not just a data as with addData) but I can't find anything online....
If anyone knows where to find its functions!**

Thanks
```

Comment: In the provided code there are unclear part. For instance, you defines "data" twice but only 1 data must be assigned to the chart. Do you want to have 2 datasets?

Comment: I see also that X and Y are defined in the test function therefore I don't think you can suing them as arguments for other function if there are not global.

Comment: It seems you have already submitted a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247260/what-format-to-use-for-label-data-and-data-to-add-data-to-chart-js